Unable to open database due to encryption key which fails my JDBC request in Jmeter
I am using SQLite database and via JDBC connection config I am connecting database and perform JDBC requests.
Now, developers have added encryption Key in database so I am unable to perform JDBC requests.
Is there any way to add that encryption Key in our request?
I have tried by adding that key in Password box of JDBC connection configuration but it didn't work. Also there is No username. Only key is there.
NOTE: I have added sqlite lib in lib folder as well. (Without KEY it is working fine)
It shows below error Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (opening db: 'C:\Users\....\db_folder\database.db?key=835b7789-de72-3eba-a47a-0ef0ffcba14f&cipher=sqlcipher': The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
See below screenshot for more details.



Edited


I fail to see where do you pass the key in your JDBC Connection Configuration, my expectation is that you should change your
jdbc:sqlite:${dbpath}

to something like:
jdbc:sqlite:${dbpath}?cipher=sqlcipher&key=your-very-secret-password

Refer to your Sqlite JDBC driver documentation and How to use Different JDBC Drivers guide for more details.

It shows below error
Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (opening db: 'C:\Users....\db_folder\database.db?key=835b7789-de72-3eba-a47a-0ef0ffcba14f&cipher=sqlcipher': The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

I have *Edited my question with screenshot

In Database URL I have added
jdbc:sqlite:C:\Users\<my path...>\db_folder\database.db?cipher=sqlcipher&key=835b7789-de72-3eba-a47a-0ef0ffcba14
but not working

I'm very sorry to hear that the solution is not working but I cannot help you without knowing what JDBC driver you're using and seeing jmeter.log file contents preferably with JMeter debug logging enabled for JMeter JDBC protocol and for the JDBC driver. For JMeter it can be enabled by adding the next line to log4j2.xml file: <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc" level="debug" />, for the driver you will have to figure out yourself.

using SQLite jdbc driver I am getting this in debug mode, if this could help you. Also updated screenshot in question if that could help further
2024-09-05 13:22:39,353 DEBUG o.a.j.p.j.c.DataSourceElement: Driver: org.sqlite.JDBC DbUrl: jdbc:sqlite:C:\Users\<path>....\db_folder\database.db?cipher=sqlcipher&key=816b1347-de72-1eba-a23a-0ef0ffcba14f User:  2024-09-05 13:22:39,353 DEBUG o.a.j.p.j.c.DataSourceElement: PoolConfiguration:testpool 2024-09-05 13:22:39,353 DEBUG o.a.j.p.j.c.DataSourceElement: Storing pool: JDBC Connection Configuration@1771780252
